# $x^2y''+xy'-4y+4x^2=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve this differential equation on $\mathbb{R}$ : $$ x^2y'' +xy'-4y+4x^2=0$$

On  $\mathbb{R}^* $   , I put $t= ln|x|$ and noticed $z(t)=y(e^t)=y(x)$
Then $y'(x) =\dfrac{1}{x}z'(ln(x))$ and $y''(x)=\dfrac{1}{x^2}(z''(ln(x))-z'(ln(x)))$.
Our equation can now be written: $$z''(t)-4z(t)=-4e^{2t}$$. The solution of this differential equation are $z(t)= ue^{2t}+ve^{-2t}-te^{2t}$ where $u,v \in \mathbb{R}$.
Then for all $x \in \mathbb{R}_+^*, y(x)=ux^2+\dfrac{v}{x^2}-x^2ln(x)$.
But I dont know how to find solutions over all $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Your homogeneous equation has solutions $Ax^2+B/x^2$, but if it is defined at $0$ only $Ax^2$.  The DE on all of $\mathbb R$ has solutions like this: $$y(x) = \begin{cases}(A-\ln(x))x^2,\quad &x>0 \\ 0,\quad &x=0 \\ (B-\ln(-x))x^2,\quad &x<0\end{cases}$$where $A,B$ are any two constants.

Comment: Since $y’’(0)$ does not exist, even though the limit as $x\to0$ of $x^2y’’$ is $0$, I would exercise caution in claiming that the solution exists at $x=0$.

Comment: In a strict sense, a solution over $\Bbb R$ is not possible. Any solution has to live inside the domain of the ODE, and the domain here does not include the singular line $x=0$.